# nothing is showing on my jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, ejb, netbeans-8, named-query

Hi I'm having a problem to displaying AllProperty data. I'm using named query 
and create a string call **AllProperty** and I'm using the sting **AllProperty** on ForEach to display the data.

my session bean

```
@Stateless
public class ManagerSessionBean implements ManagerSessionBeanLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "WebGreenWichPU")
    private EntityManager em;


  public List<Property> getPropertyFindAll() {
    return em.createNamedQuery("Property.findAll", Property.class).getResultList();
  }

    public void persist(Object object) {
        em.persist(object);
    }
```

interface Class

```
@Local
public interface ManagerSessionBeanLocal {

    public List<Property> getPropertyFindAll();

}
```

servlet

```
 @WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/PropertyServlet"})
    public class PropertyServlet extends HttpServlet {

        @EJB
        private ManagerSessionBeanLocal managerSessionBean;

        protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

request.setAttribute("AllProperty",managerSessionBean.getPropertyFindAll());
                request.getRequestDispatcher("property.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
```

JSP page

```
<c:forEach var="p" items="${AllProperty}">
        <tr> 
        <tb>${p.propertyId}</tb>
        <tb>  ${p.propertyType}</tb>
        <tb> ${p.address}</tb>
</tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Comment: What if you set properties "manually" in your `processRequest` method. Something like this `request.setAttribute("AllProperty", Collections.singletonList(new Property(...)));`. In order to check of your problem is the Servlet or the Persistence Context.

Comment: still nothing is showing. i dont need to put anything in between property()

Comment: Try accessing it like this `items="${requestScope.AllProperty}"` in your JSP Page.

Comment: nothing is showing

Comment: the worse is it doesn't show any error